# AI testing framework

Tags: c#, testing, frameworks, artificial-intelligence

I am looking at developing an AI player for a simple game I have created in C#.  I will be creating a population of the bots and evolving them over generations.

What I was wondering is there any frameworks out there that could be good for this sort of testing / development.  Ideally I would like something that I could plug any / some type of games into and say, OK so have a population of X run it over Y generations and chart the results for me.

I was having a think about how I would create something that would do this for me and allow me to reuse this later for different AI projects and all I could think of was to have some sort of core code and some interface contracts that the game and AI would use so that the server can script it.

What are your thoughts, does anyone have any practical experience of this sort of thing?

Comment: I think you should specialize your needs, because for now, your expecting from such framework to automatically know what are the game rules, how to manipulate bots, how to judge your bots performance, maybe you should start from beginning, and have some general interface, that would do the charting, but the bots themselves (or some in-game mechanism) should be the judge, tracking performance, additional data (some sort of logs, what bots think and why - great for debugging strange, unexpected behaviours)

Comment: I do agree... I was hoping that I could have a core app that would do managing charting and rounds etc.  And an interface would need to be implemented that dealt with controlling the game and the AI bots.  Wanted some way of having an AI project Game project and test framework project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called genetic algorithm framework. Any flavor is available through google.

Comment: Hi ima, thank you for the name.  Do you know any that you would recommend? thanks again.

Comment: I don't have enough experience in that area to advice any specific solution

Comment: Thank you anyway... you have given me a direction to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with AI, but personally I'd start with a standard unit testing framework. You can extend your test classes (or even extend many frameworks) with helper methods as needed.

Flipping to the appendix in Osherove's [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/), I'd start with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org) and try [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) or [xUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit) if it didn't meet my needs.

And I echo Ravadre's comments above.

EDIT: I reread your original post, and I'm not sure that my answer was sufficient. While I **highly** advocate unit testing (or better yet, [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)) during development, you seem to be looking for a way to tell which bots are most successful. This goes beyond unit testing and (arguably) beyond integration testing. My (untested) suspicion is that it wouldn't be exceptionally difficult to write a harness for your code from scratch that would do exactly what you want - run multiple iterations/permutations and chart the results. Test frameworks are going to give you pass/fail results, but that's not all you want. If you create interfaces for your bots and games, you could easily plug them in.

Comment: Hi Will,  I completely agree with unit testing, it is a must.  Where my idea differs (as you mention) is that I want to do lots of tests, for example a single bot might play 1000 games and they chart its results (score for example).  I would use some sort of fitness test to rank the bots after they have all played 1000 games.  Then evolve them and do another round of games.